Get actual RockDB Options in runtime from Java
I work with quite old java code and would like to get effective settings for RocksDB in runtime. Seems like it's easier to connect with remote debugger to running app and try to get it from there rather than go through code with multiple println statements.
Is there any "easy" way to get RocksDB "Options" in runtime using Java? Would like to check if compression, bloom filter, hash index are enabled or not.
